# Bash trap wrong $BASH_COMMAND

Tags: bash, trap

I created two traps

```
trap function1 DEBUG
trap pwd ERR
```

```
function function1 {
echo $BASH_COMMAND
}
```

If I use some wrong command let's say `a`, then output is->

```
a
bash: a: command not found
a
/home/user/dir
```

So second time DEBUG is called to execute `pwd`, but why $BASH_COMMAND is still a? Is there any way to know in the function1 that this call to function is made while executing command in `trap ERR`?

**EDIT**

Two traps are

```
trap -- 'f' DEBUG
trap -- 's' ERR
```

```
function f 
{ 
    echo "inside function f command is $BASH_COMMAND"
}
function s 
{ 
    echo "inside function s command is $BASH_COMMAND"
}
```

Output for wrong command `a`, is

```
inside function f command is a
bash: a: command not found
inside function f command is a
inside function s command is echo "inside function s command is $BASH_COMMAND"
```

The second `inside function f command is a`, must be from ERR trap.

Answer (score 1):

This can be found in the `bash` documentation (see your `man bash`), where it writes in several places about various aspects of `trap`.

> `BASH_COMMAND`
> The command currently being executed or about to be executed, unless the shell is  executing  a command  as  the result of a trap, in which case it is the command executing at the time of the trap.

and also

> the `DEBUG` and `RETURN` traps [...] are not inherited unless the function has been given the `trace` attribute [...] or the `-o functrace` shell option has been enabled with the set builtin (in which case all functions inherit the `DEBUG` and `RETURN` traps)

If you modify your `trap` commands slightly you can see this more clearly

```
trap 'echo "##DEBUG## $BASH_COMMAND"' DEBUG
trap 'echo "##ERR## $PWD"' ERR

a
##DEBUG## a
-bash: a: command not found
##DEBUG## a
##ERR## /home/roaima
```

and

```
f() { printf "%s..." "We are in function f()"; sleep 1; printf " OK\n";  }
f
##DEBUG## f
We are in function f()... OK
```

Comment: Got it, but I wasn't able to stop commands in ERR, to go inside DEBUG. If it's not able to possible, then can I identify those commands.

Comment: You want to debug the commands inside the `ERR` trap function? Then `set -o functrace` and `set -o errtrace`. It's all in the man page

Comment: Well opposite of that, I don't want to DEBUG  commands in ERR trap.

Comment: I don't see `DEBUG` commands in the `ERR` trap. Perhaps you've changed the default settings for your `bash` session

Comment: Hi, can you quickly check the edit, just want to make sure, we are on same page.

Comment: That's right. You're getting exactly what you should expect. `DEBUG` fires and calls `f` because it does so for every command. Then the command `a` is executed and fails, so `ERR` fires. There is no debug printed for any commands inside `ERR`'s function `s`.

Comment: thanks for response, the second `inside function f command is a`, is eating me, after a is failed, if DEBUG, is not initialized for `s`'s commands then who is calling `f`, for the second time.